# Are interaction history tables queried directly for pega decisioning

Tags: database, oracle, pega

I am trying to setup Pega for my application. From my little experience on Pega, I understand that when a user logs into our portal and browses something, pega uses the interaction history tables, queries them and shows recommendations to user on their web portal.  While this is a basic overview, 
I want to know if the Interaction History tables (9 dimension, 1 fact) are directly queried for user previous, current interactions. I am trying to see if there are other aggregated or some other tables/Mat views which are queried - otherwise, it just cannot keep up with the performance requirements.

The reason this question came up - I would like to give read only access to other analytics teams to these IH tables and would not want to effect performance for my end users.

This is for a completely new setup. The other recommendations are to copy the entire 10 tables into a different database and give that for analytics. 
I feel that should not be required considering Pega should allow for scalability (in terms of number of end users) and 10 member team for analytics should not effect performance.

no code

Answer (score 0):

The tables are directly queried. The reason behind this is, NBA is an Omni channel product and it uses real time data + history data. The users can interact with application through Mobile App, Desktop, Chatbot, Customer Service etc. The NBA is based on the data collected through all these channels.

*I am trying to see if there are other aggregated or some other tables/Mat views which are queried*:-
Depends on the decision architect who designed the Analytics. Run tracer with DB Query settings enabled and you will see the tables being queried.